# ggplot doesn't show the second geom_line() in my plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

My df:

```
   p1   p2 p3    x        y
    0 3000 14  0.0 0.026500
   20 3000 14 11.0 0.054000
   30 3000 14 17.9 0.057000
   60 3000 14 49.3 0.064000
   80 3000 14 77.4 0.063000
   60 3500 14 45.3 0.061000
   60 4000 14 41.4 0.058300
   60 4400 14 43.7 0.073600
   60 3500  9 41.7 0.060556
   60 3500 18 46.7 0.060700
   60 3500 21 49.2 0.059900
```

This is the result of a "one parameter at a time" experimental design, i.e., one where the parameters `p1`, `p2` and `p3` were changed one at a time (definitely not the best kind of DOE, but that's what I got). For each observation, two variables are measured, `x` and `y`. I would like to plot a line connecting all points of the `p1` study (the first 5 rows), a line connecting all points of the `p2` study (rows 4 and 6:8) and a third line connecting the points of the `p3` study (rows 6 and 9:11). I tried with

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y, color = p2)) +
  geom_point( aes(shape = p3)) + 
  geom_line() +
  geom_line(data = filter(df, p1 == "60" & p3 == "14"),  aes(x = x, y = y))
```

[image]

The red and the green line correspond to the `p1` and `p3` study, but `ggplot` doesn't plot the line corresponding to the `p2`. How can I manage to plot it? In practice, I need either a `geom_path` or a `geom_line` connecting the triangle symbols in the center of the screen (x coordinate between 40 and 50).

Comment: try adding `inherit.aes = FALSE` to your second `geom_line`

Comment: it works! Thanks! Can you explain why, i.e., which `aes` was implicitly inherited that prevented the second `geom_line` from being drawn? I specified again the `x` and `y` aesthetics, so I guess it's `color`...maybe it was trying to draw 4 one-point lines?

Comment: Everything specified in the original `ggplot()` call is automatically passed to all subsequent layers, unless overridden.